# Can we detect ibeacons through android phones without explicitly turning on the bluetooth or location?

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

How can we detect ibeacons from a android phone without explicitly switching on the bluetooth or location...? 
I want to design an app which detects for the beacon even when the bluetooth is off...please suggest the answer

Comment: iBecaons emits with Bluetooth. How are you supposed to scan if you don't have Bluetooth on? It's like using a TV, without plugging it to the current.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is not possible.  Bluetooth must be turned on to detect t beacons as it requires using the Bluetooth radio to do a scan.

With BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission (required for scanning anyway), it is possible to detect if bluetooth is off, then turn it on long enough to do a scan, then turn it back off again.  The user will see the Bluetooth icon when this happens, and the user will be told at install time that the app requires this permission.